# Problems with Polynomial.java zeros method

Tags: java, polynomial-math

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/35wcsqhf6szkvl4/Polynomial.java) is the location of the source code (using Dropbox).

The problem is in the fact that it doesn't evaluate zeros properly.

For example: `x^2-2x-8` should equal the zeros of `{-4, 2}`, but instead I get a long exponential value like `-4+34534....E-25<i>i</i>`.

It does work for polynomials with single roots `(such as x<sup>2</sup>+4x+4, root = {-2})`

Can anyone spot the problem, it's been frustrating me for weeks. This is **NOT** a homework assignment, this is something I work on in my free time.

Comment: you might want to add code snippet,link you provide does not work for me.

Comment: Try it now. I would add a snippet, but it would be several hundred lines long.

Comment: Does your code handle complex solutions to quadratic equations?  From what you've posted, I think that your code is returning -4 + (3e-25 i). This is really close to -4 + (0e0 i) which is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: It does handle complex solutions, but then what about the other roots?

Comment: @Mohit -- From what you've posted, I suspect that your issue is with the numerical accuracy of your calculations.  This paper (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) should give you some hints on handling this calculation properly.

Comment: @DavidHarris - Thanks for the paper, it did help out some, but I may just find another method or library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into problems like this before and decided to switch to a different (math-oriented) language. You could try using floats instead of doubles, which may do the trick, but would probably bear problems of their own. Or you could write a method that filters out anything smaller than 1E-10 or something along those lines. Another alternative (which may or may not be relevant here) would be to use [JLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html).

Comment: I do not have a copy of Mathematica nor do I intend to purchase it. So I can't utilize JLink.